# How to select index and delete it's respectively data from API in flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

I'm getting images from API and show them into grid view but the requirement is that I press long on any index of the image,a selected icon should be visible on that index image.
but the problem is that when I press long at any index, the selected icon is visible on all indexes.

ScreenShot:

[image]

to resolve this, I made  model class, in which there are datatype
first is boolean variable(isSelected) for each index, another is for PhotoDetails which is fetching from API, but unable to handle it with `FutureBuilder`, because it rebuilds the build method when I performed `setState` and isSelected becomes false.

Code:

Model class:

```
class Photos{
 PhotoDetail photoDetail;
 bool isSelected;
 Photos({this.photoDetail, this.isSelected});
}
```

FutureBuilder:

```
 Expanded(
              child: FutureBuilder<PhotoModel>(
                future:  _photoApi.getPhotosByUserList(
                  token: widget.tokenId, 
                  contactId:   widget.userContent.id,
                  
                  ),
              
                builder:(BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<PhotoModel> snapshot){
                  if (!snapshot.hasData) {
                    return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
                  } 
                    
                  if (snapshot.hasError){
                      return Center(child: new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}'));
                  }
                   List<Photos> photos =[];
                   snapshot.data.content.forEach((element) {
                      photos.add(
                       Photos(
                         isSelected: false,
                         photoDetail: element
                        )
                      );
                  });
                  print("photos photos photos length:${photos.length}");
                   return photos.length>0?
                   sliverGridWidget(context,photos)
                   :Container(
                    alignment: Alignment.center,
                    child: Text("Empty"),
                   );
                }
                
              )  
             
              )
```

Images in grid view:

```
 Widget sliverGridWidget(BuildContext context, List<Photos> listPhotoDetail){
    return StaggeredGridView.countBuilder(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        crossAxisCount: 6,
        itemCount: listPhotoDetail.length,
        itemBuilder: (context, index){ 
          return InkWell(
            onLongPress: (){
              setState(() {
                enable = true;
                print("iinnndexxxxxxx:$index");
                // listPhotoDetail[index].isSelected = true;
              });
            },
           
            child: Container(
             alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color:Colors.grey[100],

                image: DecorationImage(
                  image: NetworkImage(listPhotoDetail[index].photoDetail.image.fileUrl),
                  fit: BoxFit.cover
                )
              ),
              child:enable?
              Image.asset('assets/icons/selected.png') 
              :Container()
            ),
          );
        },
        staggeredTileBuilder: (index)=> view ?StaggeredTile.count(6,6):StaggeredTile.count(2,2),
         mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
         crossAxisSpacing:8.0,
      );
  }
```

Comment: Where did you declare `enable`. Try declaring it in `sliverGridWidget` method.

Comment: Nothing wrong with enable variabe. Please read the question  properly, you will understand.

Comment: The issue is with the scope of your `enable` variable. It's scoped to the entire grid rather than a single element in your grid. You can solve this by taking your `InkWell` widget and its children and moving them into their own `StatefulWidget` so the long press will only update the `enable` variable of the single element rather than all of them at once.

Comment: Could you please implement it into code?

Answer (score 0):

To solve it try to use a specific key for every image